# How to get crystallized honey out of a bowl

Tags: cleaning, chemistry, honey

I was attempting to make a teriyaki sauce with soy sauce generous amounts of honey and orange juice boiling it all down on medium heat with some starch to thicken it. I ended up overdoing both the boiling and the honey. Pouring it into a ceramic bowl and having it sit in the fridge overnight made it solidify.

The end product is a vile mess somewhere between crystalized honey the colour of sewage and a ceramic bowl of solidified hot glue. The failure of a sauce might be a helpful learning experience but I still need my amn bowl back. Any advice on getting it off as I can barely scoop it with a spoon?

Answer (score 5):

Microwave the bowl, or let it sit in a pot of boiling water, to loosen it so you can remove most of the gunk. Soaking in hot water for a while will remove the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In this case irrelevant as the end product is cooked/heated anyway.

While heating to liquify honey works, a better way to make crystallized honey more creamy and spreadable is to scrape or stir it.

At least in Germany (and I think in the rest of the EU, too) your normal store bought honey is not allowed to be heat treated at all, until specially mentioned.